# IonicDB invalid handshake when reconnecting after disconnect

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

(USING IONIC SERVE IN BROWSER) When a user signs up on my app, a connection to the database is created, and some preliminary data is inserted with their ID. This works fine. The problem comes if you log out and then sign up again, when it tries to connect again it says:

```
"Connection Failed:  Invalid handshake."
```

If I log out and refresh the app, and then sign up then it works ok. I'm thinking that something in the Auth or Database providers is holding a value from before the logout which is why the connection is failing on the new user. I had a look at local storage in chrome dev, and everything apart from "ionic_insights_session" is cleared when I log out. So I don't know what the problem is. A few code snippets for you:

When a user signs up:

```
this.auth.signup(details).then(() => {
    this.auth.login('basic', details).then(() => {
      this.db.connect();
      this.doneLoading();
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(GuidePage, {'justSignedUp': true}, {'animate': true, 'direction': 'forward'})
    }, err => {
      this.doneLoading();
      this.showErrPopup("Check your internet connection");
    });
}
```

this sends them to the guide page where:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  if (this.navParams.data.justSignedUp) {
    var points = this.db.collection("points");
    points.insert({
      id: this.user.id,
      points: 9000
    });
  }
}
```

And finally logout:

```
logout() {
  this.auth.logout();
  this.db.disconnect();
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(StartPage, null, {'animate': true, 'direction': 'back'});
}
```

As stated before, If I logout and then refresh the browser, it works fine. Any help would be great
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like IonicDB is no more. So this is no longer an issue I guess!

Comment: Technically, the correct answer. The best kind of correct :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, probably we call too soon the function that get or post the data, I'm working on it. I think we can manage this by using a Promise function.

Comment: Let me know how you get on. I've tried calling the connect and disconnect functions in different places still with the same problem

Comment: Sorry I express me bad... I think that we are trying to connect to the remote database too early.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the login process of the Ionic Cloud take some time, so I write a function to detect when the user is logged in.

```
login() {
  let checkStatus = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    Observable.interval(500).subscribe(()=>{
      if(this.auth.isAuthenticated()){ //Check every 500 ms the auth status
        resolve();
        }
      })
    });
    checkStatus.then(()=>{
       this.db.connect();
    });
}
```

Remember also to import osservable

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

In your code you must call this function instead of `this.db.connect()`

Comment: I'll give that a look tomorrow and see how it works. Thanks for the replies!